# Cross apply scope is not visible?

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

Currently I have a `udf` which returns a `table`. it returns `3` rows . Each row return the `parameter's value *10`

Something like (pseudo):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[myUdf]
(   
    @num int
)
RETURNS  @myTable TABLE (h int )     

AS
begin
    insert into @myTable 
    SELECT h=@num * 10 UNION
    SELECT h=@num * 20 UNION
    SELECT h=@num * 30
    return @myTable
end
```

Ok.

Now ,  in my code  I do something like :

```
select  .... , 
has20 = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  dbo.myUdf(A.ID) WHERE h=20) 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 end
,
has30 = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  dbo.myUdf(A.ID) WHERE h=30)
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 end
...
from A join B...on ...
Where x .. or ..y ... or Exists (select 1 from dbo.myUdf(A.ID) )
```

Please notice multiple usages :

[image]

Ok. So I was told to use Cross apply and so I did :

So let's take a real simple example :

I have this 3 rows of data :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(myNum INT)
INSERT @t
VALUES  (1), (2), (3)
```

so let's use  cross apply :

```
SELECT  has20  = CASE WHEN  EXISTS( SELECT h FROM myCrossApply WHERE mynum=20 ) 
             THEN '1' ELSE '0' END   , 
        has30  = CASE WHEN  EXISTS( SELECT h FROM myCrossApply WHERE mynum=30 ) 
             THEN '1' ELSE '0' END  
FROM   @t tmp
       CROSS APPLY (
         -- notice  ! in reality there is a udf Table here , I jsut made a simple conversion insted so you can test it.
         SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 10 UNION SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 20 UNION SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 30
        ) myCrossApply
```

But there is 2 errors here Which I don't know how to solve :

**Question #1**

- It doesn't recognize myCrossApply in the `EXISTS` clause :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

**Question #2**

- Also , the rows are mutipled becuase of the cross apply

For example ( let's remove the unknown exists clause to show the second problem) :

```
SELECT  dummy =  tmp.myNum , myCrossApply.h
         /*...*/ 

FROM   @t tmp
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 10 UNION SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 20 UNION SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 30
        ) myCrossApply
```

[image]

How can I solve this ?

*I just don't want the UDF to be recalculated each time , so they suggested to use cross apply.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myCrossApply is not a real table, it is a reference to a alias for a subset of data. 
You would not be able to refer to tmp as a table either.

Here is some code that should use the same logic as your script:

```
declare @t table(mynum int)
insert @t values(1),(2),(3)

SELECT  has20  = myCrossApply.chk1, 
        has30  = myCrossApply.chk2,
        mynum
FROM   @t tmp
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT 
  max(case when h = 20 then 1 else 0 end) chk1, 
  max(case when h = 30 then 1 else 0 end) chk2
FROM
(   SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 10
    UNION all
    SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 20 
    UNION all
    SELECT h = tmp.myNum * 30) x
) myCrossApply
```

Result:

```
has20   has30   mynum
1       1       1
1       0       2
0       1       3
```

Comment: there are 3 lines of data. for each line it should run the check if has20 , has 30. si it's still 3 rows.( difference is only as added columns)

Comment: Assuming god is holding `myTableUdf(currentIteration)` , for each line ( of the 3 ) I need to query this table

Comment: I've jsut noticed , that if [God's table hold nothing](http://i.imgur.com/ifXegxg.png) :  I'll have NO ROWS AT ALL. which is a big problem. All I wanted is to query the `udfTable( currentIteration Param)` in different places for the same iteration ( with different criteria)

Comment: In addition , [here is the view to the real problem](http://i.imgur.com/P56NQCy.png) So , as you can see , I check also if ANY rows at table (in the where clause))

Comment: found it. changed to `outer APPLY` http://i.imgur.com/72EBEvo.png , Also http://i.imgur.com/UA2vTOB.png